# Can not connect to mobile broadband even when modem is detected

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and when I connect the Linktop U100(CDMA2000 1X USB modem) the "New Mobile broadband connection" alongwith "Enable mobile broadband" appears in network drop-down menu but when I click "New mobile broadband connection" it just gets ticked with check mark but nothing prompts and there is no Internet.This same modem used to work in ubuntu 10 (exact version I do not remember).
Here are the pics that show the said behavior.

Before connecting the modem:

[image]

After connecting the modem and clicking it:

[image]

I did some attempts of using wvdial,gnome-ppp but all failed.Wvdial says modem not responding after re-sending ATZ.

Comment: Anyone if here please suggest something